# Returning char* from function not working

Tags: c++, pointers, char

Visual studio c++ shows that "string" on line 24 has one array element, but the top contains all the text that was input by the user. But when I send to PutString(), it disappears. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void PutString( const char* pChar ){
    for( ; *pChar != 0; pChar++ )
    {
        putchar( *pChar );
    }
}

char* GetString(){
    char c[100];
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        c[i] = getchar();
    }while( c[i++] != '\n' );
    c[i] = '\0';
    // PutString( c );
    return c;
}

void main(){
    char* string = GetString();
    PutString( string );
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Because `c` is a local variable within `GetString` and you are returning its address, after which it disappears (moves out of scope). That's undefined behaviour - you're not allowed to use stuff that's gone out of scope. In fact, if you run that through `gcc`, it tells you that quite explicitly:

```
qq.cpp:9: warning: address of local variable ‘c’ returned
```

If you want to return non-simple things (such as arrays instead of integers or floats, which make a copy for you) from a function, you need to (for example) dynamically allocate it so that it survives function return. Something like changing:

```
char c[100];
```

into:

```
char *c = malloc (100); // or equivalent 'new'.
```

(and remembering to free/delete it eventually, of course).

Even though you may *see* it in the debugger when you return from `GetString`, it's still not guaranteed as per the standards.

In any case, there's a good chance the next stack manipulation (such as calling `PutString`) will wipe out the information.

---

Here's a C++ version that does it the `new/delete` way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void PutString (const char* pChar ){
    for (; *pChar != 0; pChar++)
        putchar( *pChar );
}

char* GetString (void) {
    char *c = new char[100];      // memory behind c will survive ...
    int i = 0;
    do {
        c[i] = getchar();
    } while (c[i++] != '\n');
    c[i] = '\0';
    return c;
}                                 // ... past here ...

int main (void) {
    char* string = GetString();
    PutString (string);
    delete[] string;              // ... until here.
    return 0;
}
```

---

I should also mention that there are probably better way to get line-based input in both C ([fgets](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) or see [an earlier answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921)) and C++ (such as the [string getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) and the [char array getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/)).

Comment: Hmm. If it's out of scope, why does the output show the string value in "string" next to the hex value?

Comment: @abado after it moves out of the scope, it becomes undefined behavior

Comment: @adabo, so you see the output you get is unpredictable

Comment: @adobo, because the call to PutString _overwrites_ the information on the stack.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning pointer to a variable that is local to the function in `GetString()`, when the function returns, the space allocated to the variable is reclaimed.

To fix these you can either dynamically allocate space for the character array or declare it as static so that the lifetime of the variable becomes the entire program.

Comment: I see. So how do I properly return the getchar() values?

Answer (score 1):

You `GetString` will not work correctly as the string (`char c[100]`) is put onto the stack. When the function gets to the return this will be deleted.

Either use `malloc` or pass into the function the array.